# How to read TLB (type libraries) of unmanaged code from C#?

Tags: c#, com, typelib

How can I parse an unmanaged code in TLB (Of unmanaged COM server) in C#?

Comment: Do you want to do this to inspect type libraries in general, or do you want to access the unmanaged COM server via the type library information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating a managed wrapper using [tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: I need to write a wrapper code in C# for extracting all types contained inside type library(unmanaged COM server's TLB)

Comment: No, the `tlbimp.exe` utility will generate a managed assembly from the TLB which will contain all the types that are exposed.

Comment: Then how can I be able to write such code in C# to extract all types,interfaces,exposed functions with complete signatures of that COM server whose TLB is UNMANAGED?

Answer (score 2):

Once I wrote a TLB [browser](http://typelibwizard.sourceforge.net/WhatTypelibWizardIs.htm) in VB. I used a COM component that shipped with VB 6 called TlbInf32.dll (you can still find this component in the web I guess).

Best