# .net types replaced by IUnknown in type library

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, delphi-xe4

When I import tlb file that is specific to a .net dll, into Delphi using type library importer, the methods which accept parameters of type .net specific, are replaced by IUnknown. 
When I want to invoke such method from my Delphi client application, I would like to pass a parameter value of type SQLTransaction. How do I achieve this? Do I need to change all the .net dll method parameters to user defined types that inherit from .net specific types?

I also have mscorlib_TLB.pas imported when I improted .net tlb.

.net method

```
public class MyConnection : IDisposable
{    
    public int BulkInsert(SqlTransaction tran);
    {...}
}
```

Method in Delphi imported tlb:

```
_MyConnection = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{9FB088F8-1033-3A99-B9C6-C7D7D2D40140}']    
    function BulkInsert(const SQLTransaction: IUnknown): int; safecall;
end;
  CoMyConnection = class
    class function Create: _MyConnection;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): _MyConnection;
  end;
```

how do I call the BulkInsert method from my Delphi client application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is entirely to be expected. The `SqlTransaction` type is a .net type, unknown to your COM interface. How can you expect some other party, a Delphi program in this case, to be able to obtain an instance of the .net `SqlTransaction` type.

Your COM interface needs to restrict itself to use only COM types. You will need to replace `SqlTransaction` with a COM interface. One way to approach the problem is to declare a COM interface, that exposes the necessary functionality of `SqlTransaction`. Then in your C# Code create a type that implements this interface by delegating the implementation to an instance of `SqlTransaction`. Then expose a method that allows instantiation of your wrapper interface. On the Delphi side the consumer will instantiate your wrapper interface and pass that to `BulkInsert`. Naturally you'll change `BulkInsert` to accept as its parameter the wrapper interface rather than `SqlTransaction`.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. This is exactly what I was afraid of and meant by "Do I need to change all the .net dll method parameters to user defined types that inherit from .net specific types?". I thought may be there is a better solution for this problem.

Comment: If you don't need to call any methods on the .net types from the consumer side, your wrapper interface could even be `IUnknown`. In other words you might not need to do very much.

Comment: I am dealing with COM interop for the first time. May be this is a stupid question. I don't need to call any method on the .net types. I want to create an instance and pass it for IUnknown parameter. Will the instance of TObject work as parameter and the .net dll considers it as an instance of SqlTransaction?

Comment: You can't create an instance of it on the Delphi side. You'd have to do that on the C# side. At which point, why do you need to pass it around. Remember that all we can see is this one interface and one function. We have no context.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Sorry for the incompleteness. There are other methods in the interface that share the transaction object. In other words, many operations using different methods done in one SqlTransaction.

Comment: But I get your point, and it is clear how to deal with the situation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should first obtain the Interop proxy objects, usually importing a type library in a visual studio project it is done automatically by the ide, I think that Delphy ought to implement the same feature, but I don't sure..

Comment: The second code excerpt is indeed the result of the Delphi IDE importing the type library

Comment: I figure out, you should see if Delphy compliant with interop objects, I think so, but I don't sure of.. else you may search for converting typelibrary for deplhi C# projects

Comment: What proxy objects? All we have here is `SqlTransaction` which is not exposed as a COM Object.

Comment: interop proxy objects automatically created by the ide (or the framework that supports type library-interop conversion)

Comment: see also the question related to prevoius answer link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5834100/3762855

Comment: why this minus? AFAIK exists Inter Operability framework among TypeLibrary Com objects and .NET Framework Class Library that allows efficiently to invoke Com methods from C# managed code.. this happens through proxies created by Interop Framework provided by .NET. these proxies wrap the TypeLibrary Interface in a way that it is possible execute a simple method call by a .net managed language as C# or VB.NET.

Comment: Regarding that comment, we aren't trying to invoke COM methods from C#. We are exporting C# methods as COM objects to be invoked by other code.

Comment: From the question seemed to me foregone that the object SqlTransaction required were present in TypeLibrary. It wasn't clear that it were ought to be implemented. I thougth that were a import matter..

Comment: `SqlTransaction` is a plain .net type, not a COM type: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The down vote is still there. Somebody also up voted you.

Comment: oh well.. if you want remove it, you are welcome :)  but thank you for your informations and also thanks to whom has upvoted me ;)  (I hadn't to do programmer but politician)

Comment: I guess you were downvoted because somebody felt your answer was poor.

Comment: oops pardon .. thank you for your availability you are very kind.. and compliments for answers and competence.. I am a newbie